# How can I get parent class' self?

Tags: python

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class Test2(Test1):
    # how can I get parent class's self.x ?? 
    # exactly here not def __init__(self) or other methods in Test2..
```

Please... I spent hours figuring out how to get parent class' self! and failed.. 
I need a python expert!

Comment: Can you explain why you need the "parent class's self.x"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

class Test2(Test1):
    def __init__(self):
        Test1.__init__(self)
        print self.x

a = Test2()
```

You can access self.x inside Test2, because the Test2 object has the x attribute. It is created in Test1 initializer.

Edit: After the author explaining my misunderstanding, it is not possible to do what is asked, because x is an instance member, and not a class one. See gecco's answer.

Comment: sorry.. no that's not what I mean.. ... not in "def __init__(self)" but in the class-definition part.. "class Test2"

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. `self.x` is an instance variable. Instance variables can only be accessed from within instance-methods. Outside methods you are in a static context.

You can do this (pure class-variables (not instance)):

```
class Test1:
    x = 1

class Test2:
    y = Test1.x
```

Answer (score 2):

At the point of class-definition there is no object, so there is no `self` - `self` only has a meaning inside member-functions. What do you want with `self.x` in the class-definition anyway?

Comment: Actually.. I'm figuring out this.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326361/using-key-as-value-in-mongoengine) I guess it needs some hacks.. perhaps..

Comment: @WebEngineer: This question is hard to understand, but as far as I can see, you will have to look into meta-classes to solve this.