# Add attribute to object

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have an var containing all documents from mongoDB as an object. The way I set this is like this:

```
questions = Questions.objects.order_by('-openDate')
```

This works fine. When called, the objects show the attributes I expect. But now I want to add an attribute to it. Its not defined in the database, but I will set it base on some simple python code. To break it down:

- One of the fields is responses, which contain an userId and response.
- By going through all responses:

  for i in question.responses:
      if i.id == current_user:
         (Now the magic should happen)

Now comes what does not work. I want to add an attribute userResponded to the object. This way in the template I can simply ask if userResponded is true or false. To be clear, the userResponded should not be added to responses, but a new attribute.

Just to add to this, I already tried:

```
questions[0].test = 'test'
```

I expected it was now added to the first object in questions. However, this did not happen.

Please help, already stuck on this for way too long!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoEngine: Adding Fields to Dynamic Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059560/mongoengine-adding-fields-to-dynamic-document)

Comment: post your Document class if you need more assistance